# How can two mutable reference exist at same time?

Tags: rust

Why does this compile?

```
fn main() {
  let mut x = vec![1, 2, 3];
  let y = &mut x;
  let z: &mut _ = y;
  let xx = y;
}
```

when `z` reborrow `x` in this statement `let z: &mut _ = y;` there already exist a mutable reference to `x` in `y`. Doesnt this violate rust principle?

Comment: But when z which is a mutable reference to x is being defined, y is still in scope and not dropped bcz it is used in the next line.

Comment: If `z` were initialized with `&mut x`, it would conflict with `y` and cause an error, however `z` is a reborrow from `y` and because of non-lexical-lifetimes `z`'s lifetime ends in the same line as its created so the use of `y` is no longer in conflict.